# How to change File Dialog Options in IE8?

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer

On Windows XP we have testers that do not get the **File Open** Option when selecting a *.zip or *.pdf file in IE8.

Even after running **control folders** we are unable to get the Open Option. Only the Save and Cancel options are available.

While I believe this to be a Windows or IE setting, I am unable to find it. Please help.

Additional Information:
WinZip and Acrobat is installed on these machines.

It appears to be a Security Issue as we have checked the Registry of a test machine with the problem and one without. They are the same.

Comment: What do you see in `HKCR\.zip`?

Comment: @SLaks RegEdit has been disabled by the Administrator, a test machine is a black box.